# Wait for a process to start and end in Elixir ExUnit tests

Tags: asynchronous, elixir

In our ExUnit tests we initiate a process via delivering a message "at a distance" and don't receive a `pid`. When the app processes the message it spawns an ephemeral "manager" process that executes a series of tasks, the output of which we test for. We're currently using the venerable `Process.sleep()` in the hope the output is ready by then, which is not ideal.

It looks like a [`Registry`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Registry.html) is appropriate to keep track of dynamic running processes so I modified the `init` in our `GenServer` to register itself:

```
def init(arg) do
  Registry.register(App.RunningManagers, :running, true)

  {:ok, arg}
end
```

This works in the test as below, because the test process can now `Process.monitor()` the running process and receive notification when it ends. But I still need a `sleep()` before because the process to monitor might not have started yet.

```
test "outputs a file" do
  trigger_message()

  Process.sleep(1000) # I want to get rid of this
  [{pid, _}] = Registry.lookup(App.RunningManagers, :running)
  Process.monitor(pid)
  receive do
    {:DOWN, _, :process, _, _} -> nil
  end

  assert file_is_there()
end
```

Is there a way to nicely wait for it to start? I'm aware that `Registry.start_link` can take a `listeners` option, but it requires a named process and I don't want to pollute my production supervision tree with the concerns of tests.

Comment: My current solution is to use the [liveness](https://hex.pm/packages/liveness) package to poll the Registry: `Liveness.eventually(fn -> Registry.count(App.RunningManagers, :running) > 0 end)`

Answer (score 1):

You will always have to wait for the process to start, but the most efficient way would be to continue to check for it until is registered.

```
trigger_message()
{:ok, pid} = find(Registry.lookup(App.RunningManagers, :running))
# ... rest of test

# Test helper functions
defp find([{pid, _}]), do: {:ok, pid}
defp find([]), do: find(Registry.lookup(App.RunningManagers, :running))
```

You might want to alter my suggestion to have a timeout check:

```
defp find(result, timeout_ms \\ :timer.seconds(1), start_ms \\ :os.system_time(:millisecond), run_ms \\ 0)
defp find(_, timeout, _, runtime) when runtime > timeout, do: {:error, :timeout}
defp find([{pid, _}], _, _, _), do: {:ok, pid}
defp find([], timeout, start, runtime) do
  runtime = runtime + (:os.system_time(:millisecond) - start)
  find(Registry.lookup(App.RunningManagers, :running), timeout, start, runtime)
end
```

It is worth noting that you do not need to use the Registry if you can edit the GenServer and make it [registered](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/GenServer.html#module-name-registration) via the `:name` option

```
# in the MyGenServer module
def start_link(_) do
  GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
end

# In your test, see if MyGenServer is started and registered
{:ok, pid} = Process.whereis(MyGenServer)
```

Comment: Thanks, my current best solution is almost the same, I use the `Liveness` library which polls with a short interval until the value is true or a timeout is hit.